# Pass the image to img src after capturing in three js

Tags: three.js

Here after capturing the image from saveAsImage() method, I want to pass it to the img src tag and display it. Here saveAsImage() function is used to capture the object and saveFile() to download the image in the form of JPG. Here I'm looking for getting the image in img src tag after capturing it.
Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r69/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var mesh;
        var strDownloadMime = "image/octet-stream";

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            var saveLink = document.createElement('div');
            saveLink.style.position = 'absolute';
            saveLink.style.top = '10px';
            saveLink.style.width = '100%';
            saveLink.style.background = '#FFFFFF';
            saveLink.style.textAlign = 'center';
            saveLink.innerHTML =
                '<button href="#" id="saveLink">Save Frame</button>';
            document.body.appendChild(saveLink);
            document.getElementById("saveLink").addEventListener('click', saveAsImage);
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                preserveDrawingBuffer: true
            });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            //

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.z = 400;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);



            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 0x00ff00
            });

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(mesh);

            //

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }

        function saveAsImage() {
            var imgData, imgNode;

            try {
                var strMime = "image/jpeg";
                imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL(strMime);

                saveFile(imgData.replace(strMime, strDownloadMime), "test.jpg");

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                return;
            }

        }

        var saveFile = function (strData, filename) {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
                document.body.appendChild(link); //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
                link.download = filename;
                link.href = strData;
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link); //remove the link when done
            } else {
                location.replace(uri);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give what is returned from `renderer.domElement.toDataURL()` directly to the image `src` attribute.
eg.
`document.getElementById('myImage').src = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();`

Click "run code snippet" below to see it working.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, material;
init();
animate();

function init() {
    // Renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    //renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add renderer to page
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create camera.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 400;

    // Create scene.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Create material
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

    // Create cube and add to scene.
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    // Create ambient light and add to scene.
    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    scene.add(light);

    // Create directional light and add to scene.
    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // Add listener for window resize.
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    
    // Add listener for button click.
   document.getElementById('clickButton').addEventListener('click', buttonClick);

}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function buttonClick() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  document.getElementById('image').src = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#clickButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"></script>

<button id="clickButton">click</button>
<img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ff4qt.jpg"/>
```